# iS rotate view CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, rotation

How do you manually rotate a view 180 degrees using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
```

Comment: The transform property is set on *an instance* of UIView (i.e. myAwesomeView)

Comment: This is true. I've edited my answer to reflect this incase anyone else comes along without that knowledge.