# Interface orientation issue with photo gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I am making an application in landscape, but I need to open the photo gallery in the image. The photo gallery only opens in the portrait mode. Is there any way that the application can be limited to stay in the landscape mode except only for the photo gallery? Or can the photo gallery be opened in landscape?

Comment: Check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422244/ios-7-interface-orientation/20422517#20422517. I was having the same issue and solved it. You can open the photo gallery in portrait mode only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, rotation of a view could help you. Have a look at [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365898/is-rotate-view-cgaffinetransformmakerotation).

But remember, it would affect your UIAlertView.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible because it is restricted by the framework, it will always open in portrait mode

Comment: Is there any way to limit the orientation to landscape except for photo gallery?

Comment: no. It always be in the portrait mode because it is restricted. Kindly accept the answer